# How to make maxlength attribute accessible?

Tags: html, forms, accessibility

I have a form in a few input fields. For one of the input field I have a length validation, for which I have used `maxlength="20"`.

The issue here is that the JAWS users don't come to know that the max length has been reached in the input field, as JAWS continues to keep on reading the key they press on their keyboard.

Is there a way to make this accessible?

Regards, 
Zeeshan

Comment: You could also try asking on [User Experience SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You are exposing the information through the HTML standard method. If JAWS isn't exposing that information to users, then either it is a bug in JAWS or the browser isn't exposing the information to JAWS. I'd raise a bug with freedomscientific.

Comment: Cross-post: http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/58403/17023

Answer (score 5):

When the limit is reached you can detect that with `JS` and then announce it to assistive technologies e.g. screen-readers by insert the following after the `<input/>`

```
<p class="visually-hidden" aria-live="assertive" role="alert">Limit reached. You can only use 20 characters in this field.</p>
```

**Note:** remember to remove it if/when within the limit again.

You can hide `.visually-hidden` off-screen with CSS.. or this information could actually be useful for everyone so you could omit the `.visually-hidden` class if it fits your design.

And to let screen-reader users know about the limit you could put `<span class=visually-hidden>Max 20 characters</span>` inside your `<label>` 
 element. (and same goes here, perhaps all users could benefit from having that info visible..)

Comment: This is by far the best solution i've found and should be the accepted answer. Other answers state, that one should announce the maximal characters in the `label`. This can be very annoying since it doubles the length of the average `label` and adds information that is not needed 95% of the time. This solution provides the information, when and only when it's needed.

Comment: Note that `aria-live=assertive` is redundant because `role=alert` already implies it. Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/Alert_Role

Comment: FYI, detecting if current textLength > maxLength is not possible with 'input' event - because if user types more characters after maxLength, browser will reject that character and NOT fire 'input' event. Use 'beforeinput' event, add currentlength + ev.data.length > maxLength to detect it. (ev.data can be null for deletions and other cases, handle that.) You'll still probably need the 'input'/'change' event to detect when textLength<maxLength reliably. textLength==maxLength is an ambiguous because user typed characters might have been rejected.

Answer (score 4):

Three approaches, not mutually exclusive:

1. Include a statement about maximum number of characters before the element.
2. Implement a JavaScript-driven check on the number of characters when leaving the element.
3. Implement a JavaScript-driven check that is triggered by any input event on the element and that checks the number of characters on the fly.

Method 1 is simplest, but it might be too disturbing if we expect that in the vast majority of cases, the length is not an issue. Method 3 takes more programming effort than method 2 but provides for better accessibility: the user gets a message as soon as he tries to exceed the limit.

As @Quentin comments, this is really something that should be handled by JAWS. The `maxlength` attribute for `input` has been in HTML as long as it has had the element, from HTML 2.0 (1995), so there is little excuse for not having implemented it. I cannot check whether JAWS actually supports it, so I have written my answer assuming that it does not.

Comment: JAWS still does not support the `maxlength` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

you can try it, mws-stat is your input field class name

```
<input type="text" class='mw' maxlength='20'/>

var a=$('.mw').attr('maxlength');
console.log(a);
```

and then

```
$('.mw').keyup(function(){
console.log($(this).val().length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use title attribute of the text field to convey the max length. It  worked great for us on government project with users using JAWS. I believe NVDA also uses title attribute to convey the information. In addition you can use JavaScript to give audible "ding" to notify user that the field has reached the max limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<script>
  function show(){

var x=document.getElementById("text1").value;
var y=x.length;
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML="Characters left" +(20-y);

                 }  
</script>

<input type="text" id="text1" maxlength="20" onkeydown="show()">
<p id="p1"></p>
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EVrqP/1/

Comment: If a screen reader user has an input focused and is typing, this will not be announced.